# How to convert a png image from 32 bit to 8 bit in a Windows Store application?

Tags: windows-store-apps, png, winrt-xaml

Is there a way in a Windows Store application (XAML) to convert a .PNG image file from 32 bit to 8 bit color depth?

Comment: So, I *think* it's a bit complicated, but the general gist is to create a `BitmapEncoder` for png, then set the `BitmapProperties` and add a value using [`BitmapProperties.SetPropertiesAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br226252.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1). If you read the guide there, you'll see that there is a [list of supported properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dd561977.aspx) which includes [System.Image.BitDepth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/bb787445.aspx).

Comment: There is code for transcoding in scenario 2 of the Simple Imaging Sample, http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Simple-Imaging-Sample-a2dec2b0. It's just a matter of setting the properties of the target encoder.